# Chef fails to start a service on RHEL 7

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra, centos7, chef-recipe

I was running a simple chef recipe to manage my rabbitmq server on a RHEL 6, and it worked just fine, but now we moved to a RHEL 7 and the same code seems to fail. I'm using Chef-client version 12.14.60.

I was investigating this issue and what I found so far is that when you use the cookbook to execute the code block that manages the service, in background it execute the following

```
service rabbitmq-server stop
```

But the OS reply with a message saying

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  rabbitmq-server.service
```

And this is interpreted as an error from the chef-client.

Do I need to change the code to something else? Bellow is my code:

```
service 'rabbitmq-server' do
  action :stop
end
```

Comment: What version of Chef?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. According to the [chef website](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html) you can pass the expected parameter to start/stop/restart the service manually.
Ex:

```
service 'rabbitmq-server stop' do
  action :stop
  stop_command '/bin/systemctl stop rabbitmq-server.service'
end
```

Comment: This shouldn't be needed.